# Intersection number

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Supose that X is a homogenous variety and 
$T_0 ,...,T_m$ be a basis for $A^*(X).$
Consider $T_i \cup T_j\cup T_k.$
This means that we consider varieties $\gamma_i,\gamma_j,\gamma_k$
correspond to $T_i,T_j,T_k$.Now we can intersect these varities and we have a class in $A^*X$ again.

Now does $\int_{X}T_i \cup T_j \cup T_k$ counts number of points that the varieties $\gamma_i,\gamma_j$ and $\gamma_k$ intersect?

Comment: Look up Kleiman-Bertini theorem

Comment: You mean i was wrong?

Comment: I mean what you say is truefor generic translates of $\gamma_i, \gamma_j, \gamma_k$ under your group action. Apriori it's not going to be true, take $\gamma_i=\gamma_j=\gamma_k$!

Comment: So we can use Kleiman-Bertini to make these classes general and then we really get the intersection of these translated class.Am i right?

Comment: Yeah that's right - you should also check that the dimensions match up so that after taking the intersection you do get something 0 dimensional